# Signed token approvals with web3.js: ERC20Permit signature valid but allowance remains 0

Tags: web3js, erc20, openzeppelin

My app lets users make a signed token approval to transfer an ERC20Permit token, using web3.js injected.

Token contract is canonical from OpenZeppelin.

Signature seems to be valid (`permit` call does not revert) but calling `allowance` on the token afterward shows an allowance of `0`.
Also, I notice that subsequent signature calls still have a `nonces` of 0 for the address, so the nonce seemingly does not increase even though `permit` calls go through.

Here is the react app code:

```
contract = // my contract
contractAddress = 0x... // my contract address
amount = BigNumber(amount) // with confirmed decimal job
deadline = Date.now() + 20 * 60 * 1000 // valid deadline

await contract.methods.permit(account.address, contractAddress, amount, deadline, v, r, s).call();

console.log(await contract.methods.allowance(account.address, contractAddress).call()) // 0
```

Here is the detail of the signature built:

```
const EIP712Domain = [  
  { name: "name", type: "string" },  
  { name: "version", type: "string" },  
  { name: "chainId", type: "uint256" },  
  { name: "verifyingContract", type: "address" },
];
const contractName = await contract.methods.name().call();
const domain = {    
      name: contractName,    
      version: "1",    
      chainId: 5,  
      verifyingContract: contractAddress
};
const Permit = [  
  { name: "owner", type: "address" },  
  { name: "spender", type: "address" },
  { name: "value", type: "uint256" }, 
  { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },    
  { name: "deadline", type: "uint256" },
];
const nonce = await contract.methods.nonces(account.address).call();
const deadline = Date.now() + 20 * 60;
const message = {    
    owner: account.address,    
    spender: contractAddress,  
    value: amount,
    nonce: nonce.toString(16),    
    deadline: deadline,
};
const params = JSON.stringify({    
    types: {      
      EIP712Domain,      
      Permit,
    },    
    domain,    
    primaryType: "Permit",    
    message, 
});
const _signMessage = async (userAddress, web3, dataToSign, signatureMethod = 'eth_signTypedData_v4') => {
  const signature = await web3.currentProvider.send(signatureMethod, [userAddress, dataToSign]);

  return signature;
};

const signature = await _signMessage(account.address, web3, params);

const getSignatureParameters = signature => {
  if (!web3.utils.isHexStrict(signature)) {
      throw new Error(
          'Given value "'.concat(signature, '" is not a valid hex string.')
      );
  }
  var r = signature.slice(0, 66);
  var s = "0x".concat(signature.slice(66, 130));
  var v = "0x".concat(signature.slice(130, 132));

  v = web3.utils.hexToNumber(v);
  if (![27, 28].includes(v)) v += 27;
  return {
      r: r,
      s: s,
      v: v
  }
}

const { r, s, v } = getSignatureParameters(signature.result);
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFKcga4Y6Ys

Comment: Great tutorial. I reproduced the code in my app, but still getting `0` allowance on the signer after i call `permit` :/